# Line break siunitx product numbers

Tags: siunitx

Pretty much the same question as [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165171/line-break-in-siunitx-product-numbers)

The answer is from 2014 and says an update then would fix this, but I can't find anything related to this. Does anyone know if an update released anything regarding this? I couldn't find anything in the manual

Comment: You should comment on Joseph Wright's post instead of posting a question.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if it was more appropriate to open a new thread or to revive a 5 year old question already marked as answered

Comment: Joseph Wright is still active. The asker of the question may not be pinged, but you will get an answer from our moderator for sure.